# Can't play video from private APP folder

Tags: java, android, video

I have a file in the com.app.app folder. I've stored it in a subfolder so the full path to access the file is com.app.app/files/videos/file.mp4 but I can't play the file, can you please help me ? Here is the code (the xml is just a Videoview ) :

```
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class PlayVideo extends AppCompatActivity {

    String rootPath;
    String videoFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);


        videoFileName = "file.mp4";
        VideoView videoFile = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
        videoFile.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                videoFileName);
        videoFile.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get, if any?

Comment: "I've stored it in a subfolder so the full path to access the file is com.app.app/files/videos/file.mp4 but I can't play the file" -- that is not where your code is attempting to load it from. In fact, your code bears no resemblance to this, as it has no mention of a `videos/` directory. The closest thing that I can identify that would match what your path is would be `new File(getExternalFilesDir(), "videos/file.mp4");`. But neither that folder, nor `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, are private.

Comment: Thank you, with your help i did get the right path but the player is not playing the video; any ideas please ?